# As an indie game developer, how can I have (quality) music/sound done?

Tags: sound, music, assets

Besides the story itself, a game needs code, graphics and music/sound effect. I can program and I knew a few graphics designers in the web app era. However, I don't know whether to find music and sound freelancers/professionals/partners.

So how's music/sound typically done? Do you finish a game and hand it to some musicians? Seek help via Facebook? Call the secondary school music teacher? .. Please advise. Thanks!

EDIT:

I'd like to rephrase the question a bit to clarify the objective. Let's start with example. Say, there is designer which have finish a great UI concept design, and ask: "how can I find programmers to transform this design into an app?"

It won't help him much by telling where github is and how much great codes can be learned from... He needs the judgement of what are good code, in addition to how to use the code, and most importantly, the ability to modify/enhance the code to fit his need.

As a programmer, all I know a game needs some good music. The question is not about where to find music. The question is how to find musician who knows music, the music which fits my game. It's similar to the design is looking for a programmer who can turn Photoshop into .app rather and programming books and code samples.

Simply put, where did you find your game's musician? ;-)

p.s. I found my graphics designer on [deviantart.com](http://deviantart.com) Where is the deviant *music*.com? XD

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see how being an indie developer changes the problem set other than probably having a smaller budget.

Your list of options probably fall something like this:

- Have a sound guy on staff to do all custom stuff
- Contract out a sound guy from one of the many sound studios
- Get lucky and "know a guy" (online or in meatspace) who does music who will do it for free
- License existing music (the popular indie game Braid did this with a lot of success)
- Use free music

Honestly the "know a guy" is probably the least likely to pan out.  More than likely you'll get better free music that already exists.  It's mostly just going to take time to sort through the gobs of stuff already out there and seeing if it applies to your needs.